# Misunderstanding Caley-Hamilton Theorem - Characteristic Polynomial in the Standard/Factorized Form

Tags: linear-algebra, fake-proofs

so my question is about the [Caley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem). Consider the following Matrix A.

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 4 \\
2 & -1 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial is (according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic%20polynomial%20%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D))

$$\chi_A(X)=-X^3-3X^2+9X+27$$

or in factorized form

$$\chi_A(X)=-(X-3)(X+3)^2.$$

Now, according to CHT, $\chi_A(A)=0$. This is [true](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D%5E3%20-%203*%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D%5E2%20%2B%209*%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D%20%2B%20%7B%7B27,0,0%7D,%7B0,27,0%7D,%7B0,0,27%7D%7D) in this particular case if the characteristic polynomial is in the standard form.

$$\chi_A(A)=-A^3-3A^2+9A+27I_3=0$$

But appearantly, if we use the factorized form of the polynomial, it is [false](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D-%7B%7B3,0,0%7D,%7B0,3,0%7D,%7B0,0,3%7D%7D)*(%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D%2B%7B%7B3,0,0%7D,%7B0,3,0%7D,%7B0,0,3%7D%7D)%5E2).

$$\chi_A(A)=-(A-3I_3)(A+3I_3)^2\neq 0$$

So, I must be doing something wrong or misunderstanding something. I just don't get where I made a mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm sure that I'm not the first one to ask this question, but I didn't know how to phrase it correctly to find an old answer. Also, I hope my tags are okay.

Comment: This seems to be a weird WolframAlpha syntax issue.  When you used the factored form, it did componentwise multiplication instead of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Oh, that's what it did! But makes so much sense now. And how strange that it would do that. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did wrong appears to have been arithmetic. Here's a transcript of a matlab session:

```
>> A = [-1, 0, 4; 2 -1 0; 3 2 -1];
>> eig(A)

ans =

   3.0000 + 0.0000i
  -3.0000 + 0.0000i
  -3.0000 - 0.0000i

>> I = eye(3);
>> Q= (A + 3*I)^2

Q =

    16     8    16
     8     4     8
    16     8    16

>> P = (A - 3*I);
>> P * Q

ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

which shows that in the factored form, the characteristic polynomial still gives zero.

Comment: I verified it and you are right. My calculation (or the input on WolframAlpha) was wrong. How embarrassing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You have to check your algebra. The same manipulations that show that $$-x^3-3x^2+9X+27=-(x-3)(x+3)^2$$ will work when writing $A$ instead of $x$.

In WA, the matrix product is denoted with a period. And the square is interpreted entrywise. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D-%7B%7B3,0,0%7D,%7B0,3,0%7D,%7B0,0,3%7D%7D).(%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D%2B%7B%7B3,0,0%7D,%7B0,3,0%7D,%7B0,0,3%7D%7D).(%7B%7B-1,0,4%7D,%7B2,-1,0%7D,%7B3,2,-1%7D%7D%2B%7B%7B3,0,0%7D,%7B0,3,0%7D,%7B0,0,3%7D%7D)) is the computation.

Comment: Yeah, seems like I just made a miscalculation ... I want to delete my question now. (T_T)

Comment: Definitely LEAVE the question -- it's a reasonable mistake, and might be useful to someone else wondering about whether "algebra still works with matrices"...and certainly Eric's observation about weird Wolfram Alpha behavior is valuable!

Comment: No, I won't delete it.

Comment: Don't feel bad about this. Wolfram's assumptions notation-wise are ridiculous.

Comment: Oh, damn. Thank you for the tip with the period! That's very helpful.